# How to add custom XML attributes at collection time in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest exposes [record_xml_attribute](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#record-xml-attribute), which adds custom attributes to the JUnit XML report while a test is running.

Is there a way to do this on specific test methods at collection time, before all tests are run?

Comment: But there are no test nodes in XML report tree yet, what should the custom attribute append to?

Comment: I was thinking of something like a mark, that would automatically update test attributes even if the test is never run (e.g. because it is skipped). Currently `record_xml_attribute` doesn't.

Comment: It's a function-scoped fixture, they aren't executed for skipped tests anyway. You can do the same it does, but from a hook though, e.g. `request.config._xml.node_reporter(item.nodeid).add_attribute('spam', 'eggs')` in a custom `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook.

Comment: I tried running the command , but i'm getting 'request is not defined NameError